# Jacobi algorithm using CUDA

Tags: parallel-processing, cuda, gpu, linear-algebra

I have an issue with my parallel Jacobi algorithm using CUDA which does not converge. I have a serial version that works and unfortunately I cannot spot any obvious mistake in the parallel implementation. Please let me know any hint!
You may try the code, this will show that the algorithm does not converge for the parallel

```
constexpr int N{ 1024 };
constexpr int block_size = 256;
constexpr float epsilon = 1e-4;


void fillMatrix(float* M, const int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        M[i * size + i] = size + 1;
        for (int j = 0; j<size; ++j) {
            if (j != i) {
                M[j + size * i] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

void fillVector(float* M, const int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        M[i] = i;
    }
}

void solveJacobi(const float* A, const float* b, float* xNew, float* xOld, const int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        xOld[i] = xNew[i];
        xNew[i] = 0.0;
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
            if (j != i) {
                xNew[i] -= A[i * size + j] * xOld[j];
            }
        }
        xNew[i] += b[i];
        xNew[i] /= A[i * size + i];
    }
}

void computeNorm(const float* xNew, const float* xOld, const int size, float* norm) {
    *norm = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        *norm += (xOld[i] - xNew[i])*(xOld[i] - xNew[i]);
    }
    *norm = sqrt(*norm);
}

__global__ void solveJacobiCuda(const float* A, const float* b, float* xNew, float* xOld, const int size){
    int idx = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x; // create thread x index
    if ((idx < size)){
        xOld[idx] = xNew[idx];
        xNew[idx] = 0;
        for(int i=0; i < size; ++i){
            if(i != idx){
                xNew[idx] -= A[idx * size + i] * xOld[i];
            }
        }
        xNew[idx] += b[idx];
        xNew[idx] /= A[idx * size + idx];
    }
}

int main() {
    float* h_A = new float[N * N];
    float* h_b = new float[N];
    float* h_bStar = new float[N];
    float* h_xOld = new float[N];
    float* h_xNew = new float[N];
    float* h_norm = new float{std::numeric_limits<float>::max()};

    fillMatrix(h_A, N);
    fillVector(h_b, N);
    fillVector(h_xOld,N);
    fillVector(h_xNew,N);
    
    float* d_A;
    float* d_b;
    float* d_xOld;
    float* d_xNew;

    cudaMalloc(&d_A, N*N*sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc(&d_b, N*sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc(&d_xOld, N*sizeof(float));
    cudaMalloc(&d_xNew, N*sizeof(float));

    cudaMemcpy(d_A, h_A, N*N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
    cudaMemcpy(d_b, h_b, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);

    
    int iterationCounter{ 0 };
    while (*h_norm > epsilon && iterationCounter < 10000) {
        ++iterationCounter;

        //solveJacobi(h_A, h_b, h_xNew, h_xOld, N);
        cudaMemcpy(d_xOld, h_xOld, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        cudaMemcpy(d_xNew, h_xNew, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice);
        // Launch kernel
        solveJacobiCuda<<<(N+block_size-1)/block_size, block_size>>>(d_A, d_b, d_xNew, d_xOld, N);
        cudaCheckErrors("kernel launch failure");
        cudaMemcpy(h_xNew, d_xNew, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);
        cudaMemcpy(h_xOld, d_xOld, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost);

        computeNorm(h_xNew, h_xOld, N, h_norm);
    }

    for(int i=0; i<N; ++i){
        h_bStar[i] = 0;
        for(int j=0; j<N; ++j){
            h_bStar[i] += h_A[i*N + j]*h_xNew[j];
        }
    }
        
    cout << "Jacobi finished" << endl;
    cout << "N_iterations = " << iterationCounter << endl;
    cout << "Final norm = " << *h_norm << endl;
    cout << "b*[0] = " << h_bStar[0] << endl;
    cout << "b*[N] = " << h_bStar[N-1] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You have a race condition on `xOld`. You basically need grid-synchronization between copying `xNew` to `xOld` and then reading from `xOld` in the loop. This is most easily achieved by splitting the kernel into two kernels. Better yet is to avoid the unnecessary and expensive copy. Just swap the pointers between iterations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

##### Issues

Both the sequential `solveJacobi()` and the parallel `solveJacobiCuda()` are incorrect because the copy from `xNew` to `xOld` was wrongly "loop-fused" with the matrix-vector product.

In the sequential case this actually causes *faster* convergence because the usage of the outdated part of `xOld` basically creates a [**Gauss-Seidel**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gauss%E2%80%93Seidel_method) type algorithm that is more powerful than plain Jacobi.

In the parallel case the problem is more serious because the kernel-fusion now causes a **race condition** on `xOld` which in turn makes the result non-deterministic while not even providing the faster Gauss-Seidel convergence.
Such a race condition can be avoided by grid-synchronization which can be achieved using CUDA's cooperative-groups API in a single kernel or more easily by splitting the kernel into two kernels on the same CUDA stream.

##### Solution

While the problems can be solved in terms of correctness by loop-/kernel-fission, this still leaves a lot of performance on the table because copying elements from `xNew` to `xOld` is very inefficient in the first place. For both the sequential and the parallel case it is much more efficient to just swap the pointers `xNew` and `xOld` around between iterations instead of copying the actual values in memory. Additionally the initialization of `xNew` to zero can be avoided by accumulating the elements of the matrix-vector product in a local variable and only writing out the result to `xNew` at the end of the kernel function.

Correct implementation:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <iostream>

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

constexpr int N{ 1024 };
constexpr int block_size = 256;
constexpr float epsilon = 1e-4;

// proper CUDA runtime error checking
// from https://stackoverflow.com/a/14038590/10107454
#define gpuErrchk(ans) { gpuAssert((ans), __FILE__, __LINE__); }
inline void gpuAssert(cudaError_t code, const char *file, int line, bool abort=true)
{
   if (code != cudaSuccess)
   {
      fprintf(stderr,"GPUassert: %s %s %d\n", cudaGetErrorString(code), file, line);
      if (abort) exit(code);
   }
}

void fillMatrix(float* M, const int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        M[i * size + i] = size + 1;
        for (int j = 0; j<size; ++j) {
            if (j != i) {
                M[j + size * i] = 1;
            }
        }
    }
}

void fillVector(float* M, const int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        M[i] = i;
    }
}

void solveJacobi(const float* A, const float* b, float* xNew, const float* xOld, const int size) {
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        float accumulator = 0.0f;
        for (int j = 0; j < size; ++j) {
            if (j != i) {
                accumulator -= A[i * size + j] * xOld[j];
            }
        }
        accumulator += b[i];
        xNew[i] = accumulator / A[i * size + i];
    }
}

void computeNorm(const float* xNew, const float* xOld, const int size, float* norm) {
    *norm = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < size; ++i) {
        const float diff = xOld[i] - xNew[i];
        *norm += diff * diff;
    }
    *norm = sqrt(*norm);
}

__global__ void solveJacobiCuda(const float* A, const float* b, float* xNew, const float* xOld, const int size){
    int idx = threadIdx.x+blockDim.x*blockIdx.x; // create thread x index
    if ((idx < size)){
        float accumulator = 0;
        for(int i=0; i < size; ++i){
            if(i != idx){
                accumulator -= A[idx * size + i] * xOld[i];
            }
        }
        accumulator += b[idx];
        xNew[idx] = accumulator / A[idx * size + idx];
    }
}

int main() {
    float* h_A = new float[N * N];
    float* h_b = new float[N];
    float* h_bStar = new float[N];
    float* h_xOld = new float[N];
    float* h_xNew = new float[N];
    float* h_norm = new float{std::numeric_limits<float>::max()};

    fillMatrix(h_A, N);
    fillVector(h_b, N);
    // fillVector(h_xNew,N); not needed
    fillVector(h_xOld,N);
    
    float* d_A;
    float* d_b;
    float* d_xOld;
    float* d_xNew;

    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_A, N*N*sizeof(float)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_b, N*sizeof(float)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_xOld, N*sizeof(float)));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMalloc(&d_xNew, N*sizeof(float)));

    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_A, h_A, N*N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_b, h_b, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));
    gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(d_xOld, h_xOld, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyHostToDevice));

    
    int iterationCounter{ 0 };
    while (*h_norm > epsilon && iterationCounter < 10000) {
        ++iterationCounter;

        // solveJacobi(h_A, h_b, h_xNew, h_xOld, N);
        
        // Launch kernel
        solveJacobiCuda<<<(N+block_size-1)/block_size, block_size>>>(d_A, d_b, d_xNew, d_xOld, N);
        gpuErrchk(cudaGetLastError());
        gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_xNew, d_xNew, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
        gpuErrchk(cudaMemcpy(h_xOld, d_xOld, N*sizeof(float), cudaMemcpyDeviceToHost));
        std::swap(d_xOld, d_xNew);

        // TODO this needs to be done on the GPU as well to achieve good performance. 
        computeNorm(h_xNew, h_xOld, N, h_norm);
        std::swap(h_xNew, h_xOld);
    }
    std::swap(h_xNew, h_xOld); // unswap for b* calculation

    for(int i=0; i<N; ++i){
        h_bStar[i] = 0;
        for(int j=0; j<N; ++j){
            h_bStar[i] += h_A[i*N + j]*h_xNew[j];
        }
    }
        
    cout << "Jacobi finished" << endl;
    cout << "N_iterations = " << iterationCounter << endl;
    cout << "Final norm = " << *h_norm << endl;
    cout << "b*[0] = " << h_bStar[0] << endl;
    cout << "b*[N] = " << h_bStar[N-1] << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

##### Further Optimization

To parallelize `computeNorm` as the next step I recommend using [`cub::DeviceReduce::TransformReduce()`](https://nvidia.github.io/cccl/cub/api/structcub_1_1DeviceReduce.html#_CPPv4I000000EN3cub12DeviceReduce15TransformReduceE11cudaError_tPvR6size_t14InputIteratorT15OutputIteratorT9NumItemsT12ReductionOpT12TransformOpT1T12cudaStream_t). Depending on the size of the matrices and GPU, I would also try further parallelizing `solveJacobiCuda` by e.g. using a whole block per row using e.g. [`cooperative_groups::reduce`](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#reduce) to parallelize the loop over the columns that is sequential in this version. Properly implemented such an algorithm will also achieve [coalescing global memory accesses](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-best-practices-guide/index.html#coalesced-access-to-global-memory) to `A` which is a potential bottleneck here.